# File delete older than 1 day question on HP UX

Tags: hp-ux

I want to delete files in a folder that have creation time older than 1 day. How can I get those files?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unix does not have creation time. You can try:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete all files which were last **modified** more than 1 day ago.

If you want to look for files that have not been **accessed** in the last day, use the `-atime` argument instead.